# Dividing by 2 vs Multiplying by 0.5

Tags: c#

Consider the following:

```
void Foo(int start, int end)
{
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
}

void Bar(int start, int end)
{
    int mid = (start + end) * 0.5;
}
```

Why does `Foo` compiles successfully while `Bar` does not? Dividing by `2` implicitly casts the result to an `int` while multiplying by `0.5` gives an un-casted `double`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double to int. An explicit conversion
>   exists(are you missing a cast?)

What was the C# language designers' reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `/` does integer division (`5/3 = 1`). To make it do float division one of the operand must be floating point (`float` or `double`). This is because there are cases when your application wants to get access to the quotient or the remainder of a division (for remainder you use `%`). Also, integer division is faster than floating one.

On the other hand, multiplying by a float always gives back a float. To save it to an integer type you have to do the type cast yourself. Floating point values have a different representation in memory and can also lead to loss of precision.

It is the same thing in almost all programming languages: almost all of them have integer division and floating point division, more often using the same operator. Almost all typed languages require a cast from floating point to integral types.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention, WHY this behavior is like it is.

Comment: @RandRandom: expanded it a little. If this is not what you meant, please be more explicit in the comment.

Comment: "It is the same thing in all programming languages." I think this statement is too generic.

Comment: Thanks, I've expanded it

Comment: In case anyone wonders what untyped languages are out there, an example would be TCL where [everything is a string](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3018).

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in the C# documentation. On [`/` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx), it says

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2.

Multiplication operator doesn't have this behaviour so multiplying by double produces a double (integer can be implicitly cast before being multiplied as it is a broadening type conversion). The result cannot be implicitly cast as it would be a narrowing type conversion.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention, WHY this behavior is like it is.

Comment: @RandRandom Not sure what you mean. Because C# designers created it this way?

Comment: But what could the reason behind this be, why would those two operators behave differently, the OP asks specifically WHY he needs a cast for the one and not the other.

Answer (score 4):

This question is not relevant to [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html).

This question is all about why I can do `int / 2` but I can't do `int * 0.5`.

From [`7.7.2 Division operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
int operator /(int x, int y);
```

That's why it is ok to do.

From [`7.7.1 Multiplication operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691372%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

There is no `double * int` or vice versa, only `double * double` and `int * int`. Since there is no implicit conversion from `double` to `int` but there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `double`, the `int` will be converted to `decimal`. So that's what the compiler actually does.

Answer (score 2):

Got it.

`Foo()` works because everything involved in the operation is of `int` data type.

So, compiler will have no problem doing calculations because all are `int` type and the `mid` is also `int` type. So the compiler will have no problem.

To proove my point, the same `Foo()` will not work if you do this:

```
void Foo(int start, int end)
{
    int mid = (start + end) / 2.0;
}
```

because, now `2.0` is a double and calculation is between `int` + `int` / `double` and there is no guarantee that the returning number from the calculation is `int`.

The `Foo()` is doing integer division, while `Bar()` is doing float multiplication

Comment: `int + int = int` but `float + int = float`. If you do `float + int = int` then you'll get a error. Its that simple. @Stijn.

Comment: Meh. I think I brainfarted. Disregard everything I said.